# Getting "Cannot find ffprobe error " when attempting to run nodejs script

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, windows-10, ffprobe

I am attempting to use an npm package for splitting audio (https://github.com/calufornia/audio-split), however I am not able to run a single test since I get the following error on my callback:
**Error: Cannot find ffprobe**, I have read a bit and it seems that this is directly related to the npm package ***fluent_ffmpeg***, which is actually a dependency of the first package I mentioned.

The problem on some other questions/forums is that people do not have properly installed ffmpeg on their environment. In my case however, I have made sure that my PATH is updated with the ffmpeg directory (*C:\FFmpeg\bin* for me), and I am able to open a command prompt and run both

```
ffmpeg -version
```

and

```
ffprobe -version
```

I would much appreciate if anyone else has struggled with this previously and could provide me with some more guidance. Thanks

Comment: Answering your windows-10 question from a Unix perspective but it might help...  Try searching your file system for the ffprobe binary.  In terminal it would be `find / -name 'ffprobe'`.  I can't remember the powershell equivalent.  But basically when you find the absolute path(s), use one of them when you attempt to run it in node js.  Then you don't have to worry so much about your PATH.  At that point you will probably also discover how you need to edit your PATH appropriately.  LMK if that helps.

Comment: So, for instance, in Node on apple, instead of doing `require('child_process').execSync('ffprobe path/to/file')` you end up doing it like this: `require('child_process').execSync('/usr/local/bin/ffprobe path/to/file')`